# Datagrid extra column

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I'm using WPF DataGrid and there is an extra column on the right side.

How can I remove it ?

[image]

XAML:

```xml
 <Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" Background="LightBlue" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="200">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Width="200"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That is row header, not column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set RowHeader width to 0, but not actually remove the RowHeader itself, as far as I know. You can use this line of code after InitializeComponent():

```
 dataGrid.RowHeaderWidth = 0;
```

EDIT: Note that user will not be able to select rows(for example for deleting) if you do this.

Comment: Better yet, use `RowHeaderWidth="0"` as a XAML attribute. This has no place in the codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `HeadersVisibility` property to show only column headers:

```
<DataGrid HeadersVisibility="Column">
...
</DataGrid>
```